# Tools for fixing an un-balanced live hbase cluster?

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

Are there any tools/projects available for manually fixing un-balanced live hbase cluster which can move regions between regionservers  ?

Answer (score 1):

HBase balance is based on region number rather than region size, we can see the #region cross each live RS is almost equal.

Hbase supports per table balance since 0,94, you could set “hbase.master.loadbalance.bytable” to be true, and master will balance the regions for each table.

You might also need to concern about parameter "hbase.regions.slop", with default value of 0.2 
This parameter allows actual region count to deviate by this percentage from (ideal) average region count.

From my experiences, these features are pretty good for balancing and I don't need to think about other ways to manually balance.